# DOMPDF displaying pictures, but wrong

Tags: php, image, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generate several documents, and in the top left is an image that looks like this:

[image: How the image should look like]

But whenever I generate the PDF there is a very small chance (let's say about 10%) that the image will look like this:

[image: Image with error]

I have no idea why this happens. It doesn't happen to any other images in the document.

When I move the image a few pixles up or down, the white line moves as well, so it's not like there is a hidden element or something placed over the image.

Is this a known DOMPDF problem ?

Comment: Removed thanks message at end

Comment: This could be an [issue with IMagick/GMagick](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/920). If you have either of those modules enabled try disabling it.

Comment: Thank you, I think this might have fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is caused by imagick. It can be disabled as follows:

Add the following line to "dompdf_config.custom.inc.php":

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_IMAGICK", false);
```

And change line 4324 of "class.pdf.php" from:

```
elseif (extension_loaded("imagick")) {
```

to:

```
elseif (extension_loaded("imagick") && DOMPDF_ENABLE_IMAGICK) {
```

This solution worked for me

I found it here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/432

Thanks to BrianS

Comment: That might be a good addition to the dompdf configuration options until we figure out how to address the issue.